Sync losses instead of gradients in data parallel training algorithm
When using data parallelization for multi-GPU training, the common approach as implemented in tensorflow/pytorch is to:

compute loss and gradients on each GPU independently
synchronize gradients by summing them across GPUs
apply parameter updates on each GPU independently

I was just wondering why not sync losses instead of gradients instead. Synchronizing one loss value should result in much less communication overhead than gradients wrt each neural network parameter. I am sure I am missing something but something like this:

compute loss on each GPU independently
synchronize losses by summing them across GPUs
compute gradient on each GPU using the synced (aggregated) loss
apply parameter updates on each GPU independently

It seems to me the math holds (gradient of a sum is sum of gradients), but I read that even the gradient-accumulation strategy may suffer from numerical inconsistency. Is the reason maybe that what I am proposing has even more numerical issues?
